# how you concate a value inside nvl condtion?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a query that has

```
nvl(emp_num,persion_id) as employee_number
```

but now i want to make a new logic to concate e or p based on the selected value to be like this

```
nvl('E_'||emp_num,'P_'||persion_id)
```

how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NVL2` or `CASE WHEN`:

```
nvl2(emp_num, 'E_' || emp_num, 'P_' || persion_id)

case when emp_num is not null then 'E_' || emp_num else 'P_' || persion_id end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that by concatenating `E_` to the `emp_num` value, you prevent it being replaced by `persion_id` because the value you are testing will no longer be `NULL`. You can work around this with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN emp_num IS NULL THEN 'P_' || persion_id 
            ELSE 'E_'||emp_num 
       END AS employee_number
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3c35c4938d9238f084d580b48f6cdc8c)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where not returning `NULL` with `||` is unhelpful.

Although you could use `nvl2()`, I recommend `case` because it is standard SQL:

```
(case when emp_num is not null then 'E_' || emp_num else 'P_' || person_id end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use decode also to achieve like the below

```
 decode('E_'||emp_num,'E_','P_' || persion_id,'E_'||emp_num)
```